# ng-repeat limitTo automaticly trims limit and doesn't return it back

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have item array that changes in application.
When I delete items limitTo automatically trims its limit value, but when I add items it doesn't return the original limit value back. Like as limit=5 and items.length becomes 2 limitTo value becomes 3 and never grows back to 5 when items.length increases. Uplating limit doesn' work.

```
JS:
    $scope.filterLimit = 5;
    $scope.itemList2 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']

HTML:

<div ng-repeat="i in itemList2 | limitTo: filterLimit">
  <h5>{{i}}</h5>
</div>
<button ng-click="itemList2.push('new item')"> Add </button><br>
<button ng-click="itemList2.length = itemList2.length-1"> Delete </button><br>
<button ng-click="filterLimit = filterLimit+1"> Update </button>
```

Comment: Please, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the main problem is that you're adding the same element to list, so `ngRepeat` claims about it giving the following error: [**ngRepeat:dupes**](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes).

To solve it, you must use `track by` expression in your `ngRepeat`, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in itemList2 | limitTo: filterLimit track by $index">
```

**Note:** Filters, like `limitTo`, `orderBy`, etc... must come before `track by` expression.

Also I recommend you to use `functions` of `controller` for `ng-click()` instead of doing all in view.

Here's a version with all issues fixed:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.filterLimit = 5;
    $scope.itemList2 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'];

    $scope.add = function() {
      $scope.itemList2.push('item');
    }

    $scope.delete = function() {
      $scope.itemList2.pop();
    }

    $scope.increment_filter = function() {
      $scope.filterLimit++;
    }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="i in itemList2 | limitTo: filterLimit">
    <h5 ng-bind="i"></h5>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="add()"> Add </button>
  <br>
  <button ng-click="delete()"> Delete </button>
  <br>
  <button ng-click="increment_filter()"> Update </button>

  <hr> 
  List: <pre ng-bind="itemList2"></pre>
  Limit: <pre ng-bind="filterLimit"></pre>
</body>

</html>
```